# How to call the intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi In my android app background process,I need to call the intent of my class.But my activity gets opened when i pause the app by going to task manager.Please help me to solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
intent = new Intent(Service.this,PushNotification.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

If i didnt set the flag(new_Task) my app force close and i got exception.
Here is my error in logcat:

```
01-16 16:23:44.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18251): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-16 16:23:44.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18251): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
01-16 16:23:44.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18251):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:847)
01-16 16:23:44.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18251):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:276)
01-16 16:23:44.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18251):    at com.app.Service.MobilyzerService$ServerTask.onPostExecute(MobilyzerService.java:359)
01-16 16:23:44.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18251):    at com.app.Service.MobilyzerService$ServerTask.onPostExecute(MobilyzerService.java:1)
01-16 16:23:44.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18251):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
01-16 16:23:44.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18251):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
01-16 16:23:44.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18251):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
01-16 16:23:44.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18251):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-16 16:23:44.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18251):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-16 16:23:44.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18251):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
01-16 16:23:44.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18251):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 16:23:44.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18251):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 16:23:44.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18251):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-16 16:23:44.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18251):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-16 16:23:44.139: E/AndroidRuntime(18251):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Where have you placed this code? Please elaborate

Comment: "call the intent of my class" - what would that mean?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to call intent in service then

call the intent as `this.startService(intent);`

(or)

if you want ot call the intent from activity then call it as  `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: If I understood the question properly, he wants to open an Activity, why then should he call startService()?

Answer (score 1):

my solution is

```
intent = new Intent(Service.this,PushNotification.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity( intent );
```

Answer (score 0):

For opening an `Activity` using intent please use `startActivity`

Code will be

```
Intent inda = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
NewDutyActivity.class);
inda.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
inda.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(inda);
```

i think you are trying to open the activity from a `service` as you are trying to start a UI component from something that is not it self a UI component you are getting this error.

For that reason you have to add `new task flag` in your intent.

Comment: Thanks for all of your replies.I have used startActivity(intent),but if i didnt set the Flag (New_Task), my app force close.I have edited my post with exception.Please see above....

Comment: @ Chinmoy Debnath,So i need to call the class which will show notification and alert.I have changed setFlag as addFlags.Now i can able to get alert even when coming from task manager

Comment: But after i change addFlags,i am getting the notification and alerts again and again.But i need to get only one,so if i have already have notification and alert then i should not get those again.